# Remove whole div with specific class name

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, xulrunner, geckofx

Is it possible to remove the whole div with a specific class name? For example;

```
<body>
<div class="head">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="foot">...</div>
</body>
```

I would like to remove the div with the "container" class.

A C# code example would be verry useful, thank you.

Comment: Indeed it's possible. but are you trying to remove it in C#?

Comment: @Saleem Yes its a webbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way (I suppose) to do this is via built in Gecko DOM classes and methods.

So, in your case something like:

```
var containers = yourDocument.GetElementsByClassName("container");
//this returns an IEnumerable of elements with this class. If you only ever gonna have one, you can do it like that:
var yourContainer = containers.FirstOrDefault();
yourContainer.Parent.RemoveChild(yourContainer);
```

Obviously, you can also do loops etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse html in c# the best way is to use Html agility pack :

https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();  
document.Load(@"C:\yourfile.html")  

HtmlNode nodesToRemove= document .DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='container']").ToList();  

foreach (var node in nodesToRemove)
    node.Remove();
```

Comment: I think there's no point in using HtmlAgilityPack if geckofx allows that just as nice (or nicer IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the help of regex, you can remove your desired div

```
var data = "<body>\n<div class=\"head\">...</div>\n" +
    "<div class=\"container\">...</div>\n" +
    "<div class=\"foot\">...</div>\n</body>";

var rxStr = "<div[^<]+class=([\"'])container\\1.*</div>";

var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex (rxStr, 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


var nStr = rx.Replace (data, "");

Console.WriteLine (nStr);
```

This will reduce your string to

```
<body>
<div class="head">...</div>

<div class="foot">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a very bad, bad idea. Parsing html/xml with regular expressions, especially if you have built in ways to do that is just wrong:)